# Configure sysdeo tomcat plugin in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have created a dynamic web application in eclipse helios i have install sysdeo tomcat plugin how to run my application using sysdeo plugin what are the setting needed please help me

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you prefer the old Sysdeo plugin instead of the default Tomcat plugin which is already provided by Eclipse-for-Java-EE?

Answer (score 3):

BalusC: Just a note about why you might want to use Sysdeo.  To the best of my knowledge, Sysdeo is still the only free way to hot-swap Java classes (not just JSPs) while using Tomcat inside Eclipse.  There is JRebel and myEclipse, but neither of these are free.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the steps listed in the article:  [Setting up the Sysdeo Tomcat Plug-in](http://technologicaloddity.com/using-projects/java-projects/setting-up-the-sysdeo-tomcat-plug-in/).  They worked for me when I was figuring out how to configure things.